Numerical uniformization
Uniformization theorem is one of the basic facts of the theory of Riemann surfaces: Every Riemann surface $S$ of hyperbolic type is biholomorphic to the quotient $\mathbb H^2/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma< PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ is a (torsion-free) Fuchsian subgroup. In the question I will limit myself to the case of compact surfaces $S$ even though the same one can ask about surfaces of finite type (compact surface with a finite subset removed). A surface $S$ can be given as a (complex) projective curve, i.e. by a finitary data (either by restricting to algebraic curves over $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ or by using whatever representation of complex coefficients of algebraic equations you like). Describing "explicitly" the uniformizing Fuchsian group (or, Schottky group if one uses Schottky uniformization) is a notoriously difficult problem. Nevertheless, one can ask about a "numerical" solution to this problem: An algorithm that takes as its input given algebraic equations of $S$ (again, I am flexible about the input, one can work with a suitable $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ approximation of the polynomial coefficients), computes approximately generators of the uniformizing Fuchsian group or Schottky group. Much was done in the closely related approximate Riemann mapping theorem (say, via circle packing). But I know only few papers addressing numerical uniformization of compact Riemann surfaces and they do not propose a general algorithm, e.g.
Buser, Peter; Silhol, Robert, Geodesics, periods, and equations of real hyperelliptic curves, Duke Math. J. 108, No. 2, 211-250 (2001). ZBL1019.30042.
Seppälä, Mika, Myrberg’s numerical uniformization of hyperelliptic curves, Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn., Math. 29, No. 1, 3-20 (2004). ZBL1050.30031.
Am I missing something or is this an open problem?

Although not formulated in terms of Fuchsian groups etc, I believe the work of Donaldson and others on "distinguished Kahler metrics" is somewhat relevant:
"Some numerical results in complex differential geometry"
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512625v1
I wonder if it could be worked out in the very special case of riemannian surfaces
